# LAME Encoder Node.js MP3 streaming

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, encode, lame

currently my code decodes MP3 files to PCM and then encodes output to whatever format is required 'MP3' or 'other', its using Node and FFMPEG for this currently. i want to use LAME to do the MP3 conversion encode and leave FFMEG for other formats but not sure how to go about with it. my relevant code currently:
var createOutput = function(key) {

```
var encoderArgs = [];
var encoder;

if (outputs[key].format === 'mp3') {

    //encoder settings
    encoderArgs.push('-acodec', 'pcm_s16le');
    ..
    encoderArgs.push('-strict', '-2');


} else if (outputs[key].format === 'SOME OTHER FORMAT') {

    //encoder settings
    encoderArgs.push('-acodec', 'pcm_s16le');
    ..
    encoderArgs.push('-strict', '-2');

} else {

    return;

}

var encoder = child_process.spawn(serverOpts.converterPath, encoderArgs);
encoderArgs = null;


//handles any errors and resumes
encoder.once('error', function(err) { });
encoder.stdin.once('error', function(err) { });
encoder.stdout.once('error', function(err) { });
encoder.stderr.once('error', function(err) { });
encoder.stderr.resume();

//when data received in the standard in stream
inStream[key].on('data', function (chunk) {

    if (encoder.stdin.writable && !encoder.stdin._writableState.length) {

        encoder.stdin.write(chunk);

    }

});

//setup data listener
//when 'data' received on standard out stream
encoder.stdout.on('data', function (chunk) {

    historyBuffer[key].write(chunk);
    outStream[key].write(chunk);

});

encoder.once('close', function() {

    encoder.removeAllListeners();
    encoder.stdin.removeAllListeners();
    encoder.stderr.removeAllListeners();
    encoder.stdout.removeAllListeners();
    inStream[key].removeAllListeners();

    encoder = null;

    process.nextTick(function() {

        createOutput(key);

    });

});
```

i have tried to 'pipe' `inStream[key]` to `encoder` to `historyBuffer[key]` and `outStream[key]` but it does not work. can someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1):

```
inStream[key]
    .pipe(encoder)
    .pipe(outStream[key]);
```